# Question involving differeniable function and the gradient.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \in C^{1}$ , define $f^{+}(x) = \max \{0,f(x)\}$. Put $g(x) = (f^{+}(x))^2$, show that $g$ is differentiable and $\nabla g(x)= 2f^{+}(x) \nabla f(x)$.

It's very natural, I mean, It's easy to believe. However I couldn't show that, because  $f^{+}$ is not differentiable. Let me explain my attempt:

Take $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have  $\nabla g(a) = (\frac{\partial g}{ \partial x_1}(a), \frac{\partial g}{ \partial x_2}(a), \dots, \frac{\partial g}{ \partial x_n}(a))$.

We wanna show that $\frac{\partial g}{ \partial x_i}(a) = 2 f^{+}(a) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)$, but it's kind of weird

$$\frac{\partial g}{ \partial x_i} (a) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{g(a+te_i) - g(a)} {t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(f^{+}(a+t e_i))^2 - f^{+}(a)} {t},$$

Here we can have $f^{+}(a+te_i) =0$ or $f^{+}(a+te_i) = f(a+te_i)$, the same way $f^{+}(a)$...So it's confusing. Could you help me to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi(u)=u|u|$ for $u\in\mathbb{R}$.

For $u_{0}>0$, $\varphi(u)=u^{2}$ for a neighborhood of $u_{0}$ and we have $\varphi'(u_{0})=2u_{0}$.

Similarly, for $u_{0}<0$, $\varphi'(u_{0})=-2u_{0}$.

For $u_{0}=0$, $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\varphi(u)-\varphi(0)}{u-0}=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}|u|=0$, so $\varphi'(0)=0$.

In short, we have $\varphi'(u)=2|u|$ for $u\in\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
g(x)=\left(\dfrac{f(x)+|f(x)|}{2}\right)^{2}=\dfrac{f(x)^{2}+f(x)|f(x)|}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}(f(x)^{2}+\varphi(f(x))).
\end{align*}
Note that $\varphi\circ f$ is differentiable with $\varphi'(f(x))\nabla f(x)=2|f(x)|\nabla f(x)$, so
\begin{align*}
\nabla g(x)&=\dfrac{1}{2}(2f(x)\nabla f(x)+2|f(x)|\nabla f(x))\\
&=(f(x)+|f(x)|)\nabla f(x)\\
&=2f^{+}(x)\nabla f(x).
\end{align*}